# JOIN two tables from different scripts MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I started using MySQL a couple of months ago, and in particular I have found a powerful bridge with MySQL and MATLAB.

For two different sections of my project I have developed scripts in MATLAB which return a SELECT table, and in the next section I need to JOIN these two.

My intention is to call one from the other without having to copy-paste it.  For example, I have tried using a PROCEDURE for it, but it is difficult since I cannot use a SELECT result as a parameter, ¿Can I?

Otherwise, I was trying to just run the second script from the first one but also haven't found the way to do this.

Can you give me advise on how to do this?
Thanks a bunch,

Answer (score 0):

Differently than other programs, I noticed that once you create a procedure in MySQL it remains stored until you decide to drop or modify it.

Therefore once you've stored it from within one script, there's no need to call it again from the other one, as it has been stored already.